# Signed Hexadecimal string to long int function

Tags: c, string, hex, twos-complement

I need a function to convert a 32bit or 24bit signed (in two's complement) hexadecimal string into a long int. Needs to work on both 32bit and 64bit machines (regardless of the size of long int) and work regardless of whether the machine is a two's complement machine or not.

**SOLUTION:**

```
long int hex2li (char hexStr[], int signedHex)
{
   int bits = strlen (hexStr) * 4;

   char *pEnd;
   long long int result = strtoll (hexStr, &pEnd, 16);

   if (pEnd[0] == '\0')
   {
      if (signedHex)
      {
         if (result >= (1LL << (bits - 1))) result -= (1LL << bits);
      }

      return (long int) result;
   }

   return LONG_MIN;
}
```

Comment: It's not right - hex strings starting with `8`, `9`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` should all be negative too.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get a single function to do both types of string as FFFFFF means different things as a 24-bit signed hex number and a 32-bit signed hex number. Also, is working on a non-two's complement machine a genuine requirement?

Comment: It looks like you are working on a machine where `long` is 32-bits. FFFFFFFF is greater than the maximum value representable in a 32-bit signed value so, 2^31 -1 is the largest representable value so that is used instead.

Comment: I thought that you could use the length of the string to get the number of bytes so you know whether to interpret it as a 24 or 32 bit string. Basically I want a function that maps strings `FFFFFF` and `FFFFFFFF` to `-1`.

Comment: Well, you could use the difference between `pEnd` and `hexStr` to see how many digits were converted but this would be a highly unusual interface. Do you really want to treat "00FFFF" and "FFFF" as different numbers? What does the spec say that you're getting your input from?

Comment: Yes, "00FFFF" and "FFFF" are different numbers for this particular problem. The input string is **definitely** a valid hex string. So I could just use the following, surely: `int bits = strlen (hexStr) * 4;`. I have my solution from your post below: `if (result >= (1LL << (bits - 1))) result -= (1LL << bits);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a 24-bit string:

When you parse the hex string, the standard `strtol` function will read it as an unsigned value in the range `0 -> 2^24 - 1`.

The range `0 -> 2^23 - 1` is correct, but the range `2^23 -> 2^24 - 1` needs to be mapped to `-2^23 -> -1` which is a simple subtraction which can be performed as follows.

```
if (result >= (1L << 23))
    result -= (1L << 24);
```

To convert a 32-bit string using the same technique you have to use an intermediate type that can represent a full 32-bit unsigned integer in a signed type for performing the subtraction. A `long long int` is guaranteed to be 64-bits so you can use this.

E.g.

```
long int ParseHexStr(const char *in, int bits)
{
    char* endptr;
    long long int result;

    result = strtoll(in, &endptr, 16);

    /*
    ** TODO - error checking, e.g. check endptr != in
    **  Also check for range errors, signalled by LLONG_MIN
    **  LLONG_MAX and a errno == ERANGE.
    */

    if (result >= (1LL << (bits - 1))
        result -= (1LL << bits);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice and simple, and takes care of the possibility that a long is bigger than 32 bits.

Comment: It should also work even if your architecture isn't actually using two's complement which bit twiddling approaches won't; although I admit this is a bit of a curiosity given the predominance of two's complement architectures.

Comment: How would I get a similar solution for 32 bit strings?

Comment: That depends. If `long int` is longer that 32 bits then you can use exactly the same technique. If `long int` is exactly 32 bits and you're on a two's complement machine then you don't have to do anything. `strtol` will give the correct result.

Comment: Is there a way to edit the function to cover all bases. I know you said 2 comments above that it works regardless of the whether the machines architecture is two's complement or not, but what about 32bit and 64bit machines.

I tried changing it from long to int but "FF FF FF FF" still doesn't produce -1.

Comment: @Ben: I think you either need to update your question or post a new one because whatever problem you are trying to solve is different from the question that you have posted. `if (result >= (1L << 31)) reuslt -= (1L << 32);` should work if `long` is more than 32 bits, otherwise `strtol` should work without adjustment unless you're not using a two's complement machine.

Comment: Sorry, yeah it's getting confusing. Have edited the question.

Comment: @Ben: I've just realised that I wasn't thinking straight in the last comment. What I meant was that on a machine where a long is 32-bits you can use `strtoul` (not `strtol`), just casting the result.

Comment: Using a long long works. Thank you. I take it that this is guaranteed to be 64bits or more?

Answer (score 1):

We have a `SIGN_EXTEND` macro, that looks like:

```
#define SIGN_EXTEND(X, SignBit, Type) \
    (((Type) ((X) << (8 * sizeof(Type) - (SignBit) - 1))) >> \
     (8 * sizeof(Type) - (SignBit) - 1))
```

It relies on the `>>` operator 1-filling the input when the sign bit is set.  Use it like:

```
SIGN_EXTEND(0x89abcd, 23, int32_t);
```

For your problem, you could use:

```
long int hex2li (char string[])
{
    char *pEnd;
    long int result = SIGN_EXTEND(strtol (string, &pEnd, 16), 23, long int);

    if(pEnd[0] == '\0')
        return result;
    return LONG_MIN;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a generic MACRO that names the problem correctly. You could improve by using CHAR_BIT instead of 8, but that's only nitpicking.

Answer (score 1):

This comparison is wrong: `if (toupper (string[0]) == 'F')`

You'll need to sign-extend for any value with the MSB set, so something like:

`if(strchr("89ABCDEF", toupper(string[0])) != NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you cannot use strtol with radix 16?

Comment: He already is, but this isn't a complete solution as a `long` is larger than 24 bits and he has a 6-digit hex representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (toupper (string[0]) == 'F')
  {
     return (result | 0xFF000000);
  }
```

this will produce number with correct sign.

```
  if (toupper (string[0]) == 'F')
  {
     return ( ~(result | 0xFF000000) + 1);
  }
```

this will always produce positive result

Comment: What about for the first digit being '8', '9', 'a', .. 'e'?  It should still be negative.

Comment: Not just 'F' - need to check for other values with the MSB set `if (result & 0x00800000)`

Comment: @Aidan Cully:  "24bit Hexadecimal string"

Comment: @David Gelhar: i disagree. for example input was FFFFFF which mean -1. when converted to int it will become 00FFFFFF. We need to make it signed, so we fill higher digits | 0xFF000000 so it becomes real -1: 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: consider the 16-bit signed number `0x8000`.  Its value as a signed decimal is `-32768`.  The hex string that represents it is `"8000"`.  The first digit is _not_ `F`, but if you were to sign-extend it to 32-bits, the result should be `0xFFFF8000`, in order to continue representing the value `-32768`.