# C++ Reading signed 32-bit integer value

Tags: c++, arrays, 32-bit, signed

I have a multi-byte primitive type called s32 which I want to read from a byte array.

The specifications are:

- It is a 32-bit signed integer value, stored in little-endian order.
- Negative integers are represented using 2's complement.
- It uses 1 to 5 bytes depending on the magnitude. Each byte contributes its low seven bits to the value. If the high (8th) bit is set, then the next byte is also a part of the value.
- Sign extension is applied: the seventh bit of the last byte of the encoding is propagated to fill out the 32 bits of the decoded value.

In the case of U32 - unsigned 32-bit I come up with this (any comments welcomed!) but not sure how to modify it for S32.

```
char temp = 0; 
u32 value = 0;
size_t index = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if(i < 4)
    {
        temp  = 0x7F & buffer[index];
    }
    else
    {
        temp = 0x0F & buffer[index];
    }

    value |= temp << (7 * i);

    if(!(0x80 & buffer[index])) break;

    ++index;
}
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Someone asked an almost identical question the other day... I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: > •It uses 1 to 5 bytes 
- surely 1 to 4 bytes for 32bit?

Comment: @Cogwheel: It might be myself as well for the case of unsigned integers. Signed-ness caught me today, not sure how to deal with complements. Sorry if I am overusing the board (that's my 2nd post btw:)


@graham.reeds: That confused me as well but no you need 5 bytes because you use only 7 bits of each byte so you have the last four bits left for the 5th byte.

Comment: No, he means 1 to 5, it's a compression scheme.

Comment: Since it's 2's compliment and sign extended, there should be no difference between reading signed vs unsigned.

Comment: @Tergiver: Can you please elaborate on this a bit more. How about the value = -value switch that stefaanv suggests below?

Comment: 0xFFFFFFFF is either -1 or 2^32-1 depending on whether it's treated as signed or unsigned. There is nothing in the 32 bits that can tell you which way the value is to be treated. Therefore, you read and write signed/unsigned numbers exactly the same way.

Comment: @Tergiver: you are right, there are 2 opposing requirements: passing a 32 bits value and passing a signed bit.  My answer is only correct in the assumption that you only send 31 bits and a signed bit, which actually makes the encoded value 1's complement (in the byte array).
@TTBoy: please check your requirements.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong because all 32 bits are not always there. In the case of -1, it would be stored as: [0x7F]. To convert that to 0xFFFFFFFFFF you have to sign-extend it from the 7th bit out to the 32nd bit. Note that 0x7F would be stored as [0xFF 0x00].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you working on a little-endian system?
If so following should do the trick.

```
if(!(0x80 & buffer[index])) 
{
  if(0x40 & buffer[index])  value = -value;
  break;
}
```

If you need the negative of a little endian value on a big endian system, then it is a bit more tricky, but that requirement would seem very strange to me

Answer (score 0):

I posted a `SIGN_EXTEND` macro in an [answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781878/c-signed-hexadecimal-string-to-long-int-function/2781952#2781952).  For your code, I'd change your `u32 value` to `s32 value`, and apply SIGN_EXTEND as

```
// after loop close
SIGN_EXTEND(value, index * 7, u32);
```

using the accepted answer for the question, you'd say:

```
if(value > (1 << (index * 7 - 1))
    value -= (1 << (index * 7));
```